# iOS MPMoviePlayerController controls show black background when switching to fullscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use a MPMoviePlayerController to show a movie in a small box. Default controls allow the user to switch to fullscreen. Everything works perfect, but the controls in fullscreen mode have a black background and the status bar shows up, what looks weird.

```
_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:resourceURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:_moviePlayerController];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
    object:nil];
_moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectZero; // will be set to correct size later
_moviePlayerController.view.layer.borderWidth = kVideoBorderWidth;
_moviePlayerController.view.layer.borderColor = kVideoBorderColor.CGColor;
_moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[_contentView addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
```

I've attached screenshots, any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That statusbar is ALWAYS there once you are using fullscreen control mode and the controls show. The only way to prevent that statusbar is to show no interface at all (or a custom one).

Comment: Hm, that's OK, I can live with that, but why are the control backgrounds black, especially the done button looks very weird